# How to check if HTTP returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK using wget

Tags: linux, shell

here i am trying to check if wget -s returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK using shell script.
i am using this wget command to get the http status from url

```
#!/bin/sh
#
URL="http://www.example.com"
wget -S $URL
```

if i get it returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK, then it should exit else run scr.sh script.

How can i do this?

Comment: better to use `curl` for handling http specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm using exit code of silent wget command:

```
wget -q --spider $URL 
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "do something"
fi
```

In case if response is an error it runs some command.

Answer (score 1):

Using `wget`:

```
SHOULD_EXIT=$(wget --server-response --content-on-error=off ${URL} | awk -F':' '$1 ~ / Status$/ { print $2 ~ /200 OK/ }')
```

`${SHOULD_EXIT}` will be `1` for `200 OK` and `0` otherwise.